# How to set multiple values in Slack cursor Parameter

Tags: slack-api

In the Slack API End point URL, I used the cursor fields and I got all the public channels. But I am unable to set all the below curson values in the End point URL.

Could you please advise me how I can set these multiple cursor values in a parameter ""cursor  ?

Please find below the End point URL :

req.setEndpoint('https://slack.com/api/conversations.list?limit=999&types=public_channel&exclude_archived=true&cursor=dGVhbTpDRjBDOUdWUk4=&cursor=dGVhbTpDMDFGMlFNR0g4Qw==&cursor=dGVhbTpDMDFTV0hOTDM0NA==');

Here is the cursor values :

dGVhbTpDRjBDOUdWUk4=

dGVhbTpDMDFGMlFNR0g4Qw==

dGVhbTpDMDFTV0hOTDM0NA==

dGVhbTpDMDIwSFFRSzlHUQ==

dGVhbTpDMDIzTkIwQ0FDQg==

dGVhbTpDMDI2TkVCUEU3Mg==

dGVhbTpDMDI5SzFZUzNVSA==

dGVhbTpDMDJERUJDQTVBTQ==

dGVhbTpDMDJGV1M3QUtGRw==

dGVhbTpDMDJKNUhaVVNOOA==

dGVhbTpDMDJMUzFLVjNQRg==

dGVhbTpDMDJQRDhZQjBQSg==

dGVhbTpDMDJTSkVLUTlQVg==

dGVhbTpDMDMwME1DMTdKVA==

dGVhbTpDMDMyTENESEE3Nw==

dGVhbTpDMDM1Rjg5NTJVVw==

dGVhbTpDMDM4QlNYQVQ4Vw==

dGVhbTpDMDNCOE5HQ01CUA==

ZXh0ZXJuYWw6QzAySFFLOFBCNUU=

Thanks !!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`cursor` parameter is used for paginating the data fetched using given API.

 Each cursor value points to the next page of data.

You need to iteratively call the API (adding  the received cursor value from each request) and store each response, till the cursor value becomes blank.

Best approach will be to implement a Do...While loop, where `while` condition will be `cursor != ""`

**Sample Code:**

```
var channelRecords = []
var nextCursor = ''
do{
   await  axios.get(`https://slack.com/api/conversations.list?limit=999&types=public_channel&exclude_archived=true&${(nextCursor == '') ? '': `&cursor=${nextCursor}`}`,{
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${SLACK_USER_TOKEN}`
      }})
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status == 200)
        {
          channelRecords = channelRecords.concat(response.data.channels)
        }
       
          nextCursor = response.data.response_metadata.next_cursor
        
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
}while (nextCursor != '')

//This code does not take care of API's rate limit
```

You can also use ***Slack's Bolt framework*** and their sample code:

 https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.list/code

Comment: Thank you Suyash for your reply. Could you provide me an example by writing a Code for example ?